# Using "From Multiple Tables" or "Join" performance difference

Tags: sql, database-performance

```
 Select A.*,B* from A,B  where A.ID = B.SOMEID
```

or

```
 Select A.*,B* from A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.SOMEID
```

What is difference between two usages and when to use what?

Edit: I know that when we use join we have some options such as outer,left or right. But i wonder which one is suitable for specific cases?

Comment: Same execution. Old style, implicit JOIN (not recommended), or modern, explicit JOIN (recommended).

Comment: The DBMS will execute the query the same, so use a join.

Comment: @SaggingRufus, both are joins... (implicit or explicit.)

Comment: @jarlh I am just trying answer "from multiple tables" or "join" part of the question. I am aware that these are both joins and that the DBMS will handle these queries exactly the same. I just wanted to clarify he should use the join syntax.

Comment: You could read this topic for more information: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @SaggingRufus, yes, you know that, but OP didn't. I just wanted to clarify that both ways are joins.